# Creating a function to standardize categorical variables (python)

Tags: python, pandas, function, numpy, loops

I don't know if it is right to say "standardize" categorical variable string, but basically I want to create a function to set all observations F or f in the column below to 0 and M or m to 1:

```
> df['gender']

gender
  f
  F
  f
  M
  M
  m
```

I tried this:

```
def padroniza_genero(x):
    if(x == 'f' or x == 'F'):
        replace(['f', 'F'], 0)
    else:
        replace(1)
        
df1['gender'] = df1['gender'].apply(padroniza_genero)
```

But I got an error:

```
NameError: name 'replace' is not defined
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: What do you expect `replace(1)` to do?

Comment: And why/where do you think/expect it to be defined?

Comment: You should check the docs. As you see here, it is called df.replace () https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html

Comment: What observations? Why would `replace(1)` change some random unreferenced variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `replace` function defined in your code.

Back to your goal, use a vector function.

Convert to lower and map f->0, m->1:

```
df['gender_num'] = df['gender'].str.lower().map({'f': 0, 'm': 1})
```

Or use a comparison (not equal to f) and conversion from boolean to integer:

```
df['gender_num'] = df['gender'].str.lower().ne('f').astype(int)
```

output:

```
  gender  gender_num
0      f           0
1      F           0
2      f           0
3      M           1
4      M           1
5      m           1
```

##### generalization

you can generalize to ant number of categories using [`pandas.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html). Advantage: you will get a real `Categorical` type.

*NB. the number values is set depending on whatever values comes first, or lexicographic order if `sort=True`*:

```
s, key = pd.factorize(df['gender'].str.lower(), sort=True)
df['gender_num'] = s

key = dict(enumerate(key))
# {0: 'f', 1: 'm'}
```